# Spring integration ws:outbound-gateway jaxb internal server error[500]

Tags: java, web-services, spring, apache-camel, spring-integration

I am trying to invoke, a webservice(spring-ws) from spring integration using ws:outbound-gateway. I have used jaxb2marshaller for oxm mapping. Initially I have used a jms:inbound-channel-adapter, to recieve input object, convert it to JAXBElement(Sample), where in Sample is generated by JAXB from WS-XSD schema. The object factory is used to get JAXBElement.

I am receiving error Internal Server error[500] at client(Spring-Integration) when executed. And on service end(Spring-WS) is throws, Found invalid char '-', expecting '>'. The same service(Spring-ws) works fine and replies well with an Axis-2 client. So I assume there is no issue on service end and the message sent from client(spring-integration) is improper.

Please suggest me if there is a proper way of doing this, or am I missing something

Spring_integration client

```
<int:channel id="wsChainInboundChannel"/>
<int:chain input-channel="wsChainInboundChannel" output-channel="wsInboundChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="jms2wsTransform" method="jmsOrderToWSEmployee"/>
</int:chain>
<int:channel id="wsInboundChannel"/>
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="wsOutboundGateway" request-channel="wsInboundChannel" uri="http://localhost:8081/mywebservice/servicelayer"
  marshaller="masterdatajaxb2Marshaller" unmarshaller="masterdatajaxb2Marshaller"
  reply-channel="wsOutboundChannel" message-factory="messageFactory"/>

 <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean class="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<int:channel id="wsOutboundChannel"/>
```

jmsOrderToWSEmployee method in jms2wsTransform is

```
public class WS2JMSTransformer {
private final ObjectFactory jaxbFactory = new ObjectFactory();

public JAXBElement<TEmployeeBySecurityRequest> jmsOrderToWSEmployee(Message<Order> message){
    Order order = message.getPayload();
    TEmployeeBySecurityRequest request = new TEmployeeBySecurityRequest();
    request.setEmployeeId(order.getOrderQuantity().longValue());
    return jaxbFactory.createEmployeeBySecurityRequest(request);
}
}
```

With TCP Monitor normal well executed request SOAP is

```
--MIMEBoundary_57eb271a7b65c0bacefa0a80da1b203d0661422ab29d24a3
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.47eb271a7b65c0bacefa0a80da1b203d0661422ab29d24a3@apache.org>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>  
<ns1:employeeBySecurity_Request xmlns:ns1="http://com/clickandbuy/mywebservice/">   
<ns1:employeeId>12312</ns1:employeeId></ns1:employeeBySecurity_Request></soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_57eb271a7b65c0bacefa0a80da1b203d0661422ab29d24a3--
```

And with Spring_integartion client SOAP(error one) is,

```
------=_Part_0_157378300.1372091736608
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-  
ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:employeeBySecurity_Request   
xmlns:ns2="http://com/clickandbuy/mywebservice/"><ns2:employeeId>6</ns2:employeeId>
</ns2:employeeBySecurity_Request></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
------=_Part_0_157378300.1372091736608--
```

I observe that 
    ?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
and few other things missing. Is there some way to resolve this

Thanks

Comment: In order to get help with issues like this, you need to show your complete client and server configuration, a full stack trace (server side) and, preferably, capture the SOAP messages using a TCP monitor or by configuring a logging interceptor: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoint-interceptor

Comment: Hi Russell, I have updated code and TCP Monitor request content. Please helpif some way I can fix this

Comment: The `<?xml...` part shouldn't make any difference; however, I don't understand why (either one) are multi-part MIME; it should be a simple HTTP POST; you need to show the full request, not just the MIME part. Also, you didn't show the full stack trace on the server.

Comment: I guess it is multipart because in masterdatajaxb2Marshaller mtom was enabled. If I disable that part as `<!--   <property name="mtomEnabled" value="true"/> -->` it works fine. But is there some reason like WebServiceTemplate of spring-integration don't support mtom or so... Please help me understand. Note: It works fine if mtomEnable=false

Comment: Hi Russell, the messageFactory bean when mtomEnabled=true was of SaajSoapMessageFactory, which was causing error. If I change it to org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory it works fine even if mtomEnabled=true for jaxb marshaller. There is some difference in handling mtom between saaj and axiom. Please help me know if anything more on this  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi at last I could find the problem. For masterdatajaxb2Marshaller which is a JAXB marshaller bean there is a property called mtomEnabled which was true in my configuration for sending/receiving attachments with SOAP messages.

```
<property name="mtomEnabled" value="true"/>
```

And as above the messageFactory is SaajSoapMessageFactory, which somehow was causing error. If i change the message factory to AxiomSoapMessageFactory it works fine.

```
<bean id="messageFactory"  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory">

</bean>
```